# Can the coin change problem be solved with integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

**The question:** Given an infinite number of quarters (25 cents), dimes (10 cents), nickels (5 cents), and pennies (1 cent), calculate the number of ways of representing n cents.

This was originally a problem from a coding textbook, but I was wondering whether or not a more calculus based approach would work.

Some of my thoughts:

- For simplicity, if I assume just 3 different coins, then I get some combination of x, y, and z to represent a 3-dimensional plane. Arbitrarly I chose 
  `25x + 10y + 5z = 100`, where x is some number of 25 centers, y is some number of 10 cents, and z is some number of 5 cents for a total of 100 cents.

[3-d unconstrained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5V6L.png)

And then we limit the graph to its realistic dimensions `{x, 0, 22}, {y, 0, 22}, {z, 0, 22}]`, we get

[3-d constrained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjgCu.png)

Which contains a limited surface area we can calculate using a surface integral (the total sum of solutions). We can then round down the final solution with `floor()` to a discrete number.

$$\iint_S f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$

Does this approach work? Please share some of your thoughts.

Comment: You didn't tell use anything about how you came up with the graph so we can't actually help you.  Also how to do you that rounding will work?